How to make boost::python use the Python embeddable package
I'm currently working on a 32-bit C++ DLL in Visual Studio 2022 which uses boost::python to embed Python code. For my builds I use the include and lib directories from a full installation of 32-bit Python on my machine, as the Python embeddable package doesn't ship with these header or lib files. However when actually running I want it to use the interpreter in the embeddable package. I think this should be as simple as getting it to open the Python312.dll file from inside the embeddable package directory, however I can't figure ou how to make it not prefer the DLL from the full python installation on my PATH. I have tried explicitly loading the DLL with LoadLibrary, but I think boost::python is already implicitly linked with the other DLL which takes precedence. Is there something I'm missing here? Please let me know if you need any more information, thanks.

It’s from a .EXE context?  You may need to set the path to your python .DLL in your application with SetEnvironmentVariable
I fought around with this a bit and decided to use the default installation of Python, this way users could use PIP normally.  I have a DLL linked with Python and boost::python, that loads into AutoCAD, maybe you can find some inspiration https://github.com/CEXT-Dan/PyRx
